# Mysql Order by a first column and then second one

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'd have to make a SELECT ordering by first a column and then by another column... Is it possibile?

Comment: yes offcourse please provide your sql query

Comment: Yes, it's simple: SELECT ... ORDER BY firstColumn, secondColumn;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY colum1, column2
```